# I can not transfer my app into sd card on Huawei Y9 2018

Tags: active-sync

There is no such option in the device and it is running on android 8.0

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Settings** -> **Apps** -> **info/App info** -> **Storage**

Here change the storage to SD card

Reboot the phone after this, if required.